# express-generator and react app - network error 500 (internal server error)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, http-status-code-500

I'm creating a react app with an express backend for the first time. I've already ran into an issue at the beginning. When I run the react app in the browser, I get a network 500 error, and the information I'm trying to access from the backend isn't shown.
Here is the code I changed in express folder routes/users:

```
var router = express.Router();

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  //res.send('respond with a resource');

  res.json([{
    id: 1,
    username: "sam"
  }, {
    id: 2,
    username: "allie"
  }]);
});

module.exports = router;
```

Here is my app.js filed in my react app:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  state = {users: []}

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('/users')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(users => this.setState({ users }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Users</h1>
        {this.state.users.map(user =>
          <div key={user.id}>{user.username}</div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

All I see on the screen is the 'Users' h1 tag I have in the app.js file.
Any help on why I'm getting the network error?

Answer (score 0):

You should try fetching the whole backend domain. If you're using both react and express locally, chances are you're running them on different ports, so in the first section of your fetch method write the whole localhost for example

```
fetch("http://localhost:8000/users)
```

instead.